# Двусторонняя печать, что означают параметры Duplex?

Tags: delphi, принтер, ravereport

В Rave Report есть управление двусторонней печатью. Что означают эти все параметры?

```
dupSimplex  
dupHorizontal  
dupVertical
```

`dupVertical` понятно, `dupHorizontal` - как-то не очень, а вот что такое `dupSimplex` - вообще не ясно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Из инструкции](https://www.nevrona.com/download/RaveDevRef.pdf):

> This property will set the duplex mode for the current printer. Not all printers or drivers support duplex printing, use SupportDuplex to determine availability.
>   dupSimplex - Simplex mode (Duplex mode NOT initialized)
>   dupHorizontal - Duplex mode initialized - print Head to Toe
>   dupVertical - Duplex mode initialized - print Head to Head

Перевод:

- dupSimplex - без дуплекса (печать на одной стороне листа);
- dupHorizontal - переворот страниц вдоль горизонтальной оси (низ одной стороны = верх другой);
- dupVertical - переворот страниц вдоль вертикальной оси (листать справа-налево, как книга).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в основном волновал параметр dupSimplex.

Answer (score 3):

`dupSimplex`  - не использовать двухстороннюю печать

`dupHorizontal`  - двухсторонняя печать, переворачивать страницы относительно длинного края

`dupVertical` - двухсторонняя печать, переворачивать страницы относительно короткого края

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в основном волновал параметр dupSimplex.